# Is SetDelayed creating Functions?

Tags: core-language

I was trying to create a named function using a short syntax (I mean avoid writing Function[]). I thought SetDelayed was the short for Function[], but then I had some issues and realized that maybe #x and x_ may not be just alternative form to express the same concept.

Can you help me to better understand what changes between them?

(below: the named function I was trying to define and an example for SetDelayed usage taken from the wolfram reference)

```
createAssociation[#x, #label] := <| x -> label|> &


In[1]:= f[x_] := Expand[x^2]    
In[2]:= f[a + b]    
Out[2]= a^2 + 2 a b + b^2
```

Comment: Try: `x = RandomReal[]; Table[x, {5}]` and then try: `x := RandomReal[]; Table[x, {5}]` : The `SetDelayed` is evaluated when needed, whereas `Set` is evaluated immediately upon execution.

Comment: The short form for `Function` would be to write it like this: `createAssociation = {x, label} |-> <|x -> label|>`. You might as well just do: `createAssociation[x_, label_] := <|x -> label|>` instead, unless you need this function temporarily somewhere and want to avoid redefinition.

Comment: @flinty, but so createAssociation[x_, label_] := <|x -> label|> is the same as writing createAssociation[#x, #label] := <|x -> label|> ? And using Function? Is still similar?

Comment: @Revious the thing you're doing with # is not valid syntax. Creating a function with `:=` / `SetDelayed` is not the same thing as using `Function` / `&`. For example, let: `f = Function[{x}, x^2]; g[x_] := x^2` then `DownValues[f]` is empty while `DownValues[g]` will give `{HoldPattern[g[x_]] :> x^2}`

Comment: @flinty, very interesting how can I find more information on the difference between them?